# How do I combine adjacent date sequences with different increments?

Tags: r, date

I want to synthesize a sequence of dates that approximates the occasions when a patient would have had a procedure. The starting point is taking a history in which they something such as this, "Somewhere in the winter of 1967, probably early February, I had my first operation where papilloma were removed from my voice box so I could breathe and then I had the procedure every 10 days or so until May of that year. Then I had the procedure every 3 months and from 1969 I had the procedure about once a year till I started high school which was in 1972."

I know how to do `seq.Date`but how do I make the last date of the first sequence become the first date of the second sequence and etc and combine them all into one long vector of dates? My preference is to use base R syntax or data.table but I would be grateful for any elegant solution.

I will be eliciting these kind of histories for scores of patients.

I would like a vector that looks something such as the first column here

| date | days after last | approximate change over | reported frequency |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1967-02-06 |  | 1967-02-06 | every 10 days |  |
| 1967-02-16 | 10 |  |  |  |
| 1967-02-26 | 10 |  |  |  |
| 1967-03-08 | 10 |  |  |  |
| 1967-03-18 | 10 |  |  |  |
| 1967-03-28 | 10 |  |  |  |
| 1967-04-07 | 10 |  |  |  |
| 1967-04-17 | 10 |  |  |  |
| 1967-04-27 | 10 |  |  |  |
| 1967-05-07 | 10 | 1967-05-15 | every 3 months |  |
| 1967-08-06 | 91 |  |  |  |
| 1967-11-05 | 91 |  |  |  |
| 1968-02-04 | 91 |  |  |  |
| 1968-05-06 | 91 |  |  |  |
| 1968-08-05 | 91 |  |  |  |
| 1968-11-04 | 91 |  |  |  |
| 1969-11-05 | 365 | 1969-01-01 | annually |  |
| 1970-11-05 | 365 |  |  |  |
| 1971-11-05 | 365 |  |  |  |
| 1972-11-04 | 365 |  |  |  |

Comment: Can you use something like `seq.Date(as.Date("1967-2-6"), as.Date("1967-5-15"), by = '10 days')` and `seq.Date(as.Date('1967-05-15'), as.Date('1969-1-1'), by = '3 months')` to construct the vector?  Or are you starting from a data frame with only "date", "approximate change over" and "reported frequency", and you want to construct a new data frame with the "days after last"?

Comment: `library(data.table)`  
`c(seq.Date(from = as.IDate("1967-02-06"), to = as.IDate("1967-05-15"), by = 10),
  seq.Date(from = as.IDate("1967-05-15"), to = as.IDate("1969-01-01"), by = 365.25/4),
  seq.Date(from = as.IDate("1969-01-01"), to = as.IDate("1972-08-25"), by = 365.25))` is no good since it generates a vector where the days between procedures are too brief at the points of change over.

Comment: I am starting with a narrative history.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're trying to take the verbiage, define some "rules", and let it run to completion. Something like this will create your `$date` column above:

```r
ndays <- c(10, 91, 365)
ends <- as.Date(c("1967-05-01", "1968-09-01", "1972-01-01"))
days <- as.Date("1967-02-06")
ind <- 1L
while (TRUE) {
  if (days[length(days)] > ends[ind]) {
    ind <- ind + 1L
    if (ind > length(ndays)) break
  }
  days <- c(days, days[length(days)] + ndays[ind])
}
days
#  [1] "1967-02-06" "1967-02-16" "1967-02-26" "1967-03-08" "1967-03-18" "1967-03-28" "1967-04-07" "1967-04-17"
#  [9] "1967-04-27" "1967-05-07" "1967-08-06" "1967-11-05" "1968-02-04" "1968-05-05" "1968-08-04" "1968-11-03"
# [17] "1969-11-03" "1970-11-03" "1971-11-03" "1972-11-02"
```

Notwithstanding the slight difference in adding "3 months" (not always 91 days) and "1 year" (not always 365 days).

Choice of `ends` values:

- *"until May that year"* means that any date starting on May 1 should trigger changing the frequency;
- *"and from 1969"*, well, we need to know that the existing frequency up until 1969 is 3 months, so we know that 1969 minus three months is roughly `"1968-09-01"`, so any treatments after Sep 1 will cause a shift in frequency to 365 days;
- similarly, *"till  ... 1972"* suggests that anything after `"1972-01-01"` should trigger "end of sequence".

---

If you know how many treatments you have with each gap, then we can fashion an `rle`-like object and then "inverse" it.

Quick demo of an run-length encoding:

```r
rle(c(10,10,10,91,91,365,365,365))
# Run Length Encoding
#   lengths: int [1:3] 3 2 3
#   values : num [1:3] 10 91 365
```

So we can create a named-list and then use `inverse.rle` on it:

```r
r <- list(lengths=c(9, 6, 4), values=c(10, 91, 365))
as.Date("1967-02-06") + inverse.rle(r)
#  [1] "1967-02-16" "1967-02-16" "1967-02-16" "1967-02-16" "1967-02-16" "1967-02-16" "1967-02-16" "1967-02-16"
#  [9] "1967-02-16" "1967-05-08" "1967-05-08" "1967-05-08" "1967-05-08" "1967-05-08" "1967-05-08" "1968-02-06"
# [17] "1968-02-06" "1968-02-06" "1968-02-06"
```

Comment: Thank you very much. The key here was `while` and `break`.  My head hurts when I try to follow what you did but regardless, it works.